# Why i can't install RStudio in ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: rstudio, ubuntu-19.04

I can't install RStudio in Ubuntu 19.04, it gives me the following error in the terminal, I really appreciate the guidance you can give me, thanks

```
$ sudo dpkg -i rstudio-1.2.5042-amd64.deb
```

(Reading database ... 302725 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack rstudio-1.2.5042-amd64.deb ...
Unpacking rstudio (1.2.5042) over (1.2.5042) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rstudio:
 rstudio depends on libclang-dev; however:
  Package libclang-dev is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package rstudio (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.32.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-4ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.10-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 rstudio

```
libclang-dev depends of libclang-8-dev -> libobjc-8-dev -> libobjc4-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo apt-get install gdebi-core` and then `sudo gdebi rstudio-1.2.5042-amd64.deb`. `gdebi` will install the dependencies automatically for you.

There is another way with `apt` if you don't want to install `gdebi`; I believe the syntax is `sudo apt install ./rstudio-1.2.5042-amd64.deb`.

Alternatively, if you already forced `dpkg` to install the package, you can run `sudo apt-get --fix-broken install` to install the dependencies.

Comment: Thank you, for your answer and your time, the way that i resolved this, was to change the OS Ubuntu 19.10 by 18.04, that it's long term support (LTS), and more stable version, the installation of R softaware was easy.

Answer (score 0):

Try install version
rstudio-xenial-1.1.456-amd64.deb in

https://www.rstudio.org/download/daily/desktop/ubuntu64/

Bro!